# Raw image in RESTeasy

Tags: java, image, resteasy

I have this service with RESTeasy:

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public BufferedImage get(@PathParam("name") String name) {

    Monitor m = Monitor.getMonitor(name);

    if (m == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return m.getImage();
}
```

then I get after request

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.awt.image.BufferedImage of media type: image/jpeg
```

Is there any "direct way" to get the image into the response ?

---

Thanks to @Robert for directions. Here working code:

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public byte[] get(@PathParam("name") String name) {

    Monitor m = Monitor.getMonitor(name);

    if (m == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(m.getImage(),"jpeg",bo);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    return bo.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to

- encode the `BufferedImage` as JPG. Take a look at class `javax.imageio.ImageIO`
- declare your method to return a `byte[]`
- make sure that your application will always run on a server that is not started with `java.awt.headless=true` (i.e. no graphics subsystem)

Please let us know if that works, cause I have no idea if it will and can't try it myself right now.

Comment: Not shure about the comment about headless, i have run with headless=true and it works as expected.

Comment: Well, I was assuming that the classes `Monitor` and `ImageIO` wouldn't work in headless mode. If they do, great!

Comment: @Produces("image/jpeg") i was missing this one, instead i used @Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)

Comment: Returning InputStream instead of byte[] would also do a trick

Comment: Update: DO NOT return InputStream, RestEasy is not closing it, I've noticed the .jpg files being locked